# How to alias some path in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a directory with HTML files which I serve with express:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);

server.listen(8080);
// Serve /web subdirectory of this directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/web"));
```

This allows anyone to access a file in `web/` directory to access it via `http://X.X.X.X:8080/file.html`.

But I also have another directory somewhere else. Basically I would like to serve `../../some_directory` as `http://X.X.X.X:8080/some_directory/` including any of it's subdirectories.

How can I do it? Is there something like `app.use_as("file path", "URL path")` to serve path as URL?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the path to use as the first argument of `app.use` ([reference](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)):

```
app.use("/some_directory/", express.static(__dirname + "/../../some_directory/"));
```

This will serve files `../../some_directory/file` directory under `http://host/some_directory/file`, including subdirectories.

Comment: I think this really should work, but I keep getting 404 errors. Are you sure it can be safely combined with `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/web"));`? I need to access both paths.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to safely combine them (if no files match a path in the first directory listed, it will just continue and test the next one). I don't know what could be wrong, but you may want to double-check that the paths you use are correct.

Comment: I'll do some more checking. I don't know how to get some helpful error output out of Express. If all fails, I'll make a sample repo to illustrate how it doesn't work.